# How to send a second parameter of event handler while handling an event in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, event-handling

I have a TreeView. There are two parameters `treeView_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` when event `TreeViewItem.Expanded` is handled using code-behind approach:

*XAML:*

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" TreeViewItem.Expanded="treeView_Expanded"/>
```

*Code-behind:*

```
private void treeView_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
     //***I take THE SECOND PARAMETER to work ***
     TreeViewItem item = e.Source as TreeViewItem;

}
```

However, when I am handling `TreeViewItem.Expanded` event using MVVM rules, I always take the first parameter `object sender`. But I would like to take the second parameter `RoutedEventArgs e`:

*XAML:*

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Person}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <helper:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="TreeViewItem.Expanded">
         <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetNewTreeViewItemCommand}"/>
      </helper:RoutedEventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

*ViewModel:*

```
public DelegateCommand<RoutedEventArgs> GetNewTreeViewItemCommand { get; set; }
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   GetNewTreeViewItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(LoadNewTreeViewITem);
}

private void LoadNewTreeViewITem(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //e is "object sender"(the FIRST parameter), but I want to take  
   //RoutedEventArgs e(the SECOND parameter)             
}
```

How can I send the second parameter when handling event in MVVM?

Comment: In your InvokeCommandAction set the CommandParameter to whatever you want to send to the function. I don't know how to bind to the RoutedEvent, but using CommandParameter is how you would send it. CommandParameter is a property you can set in the xaml wherever you can set the Command property

Comment: @GordonAllocman yeah. I've tried to use 'CommandParameter', but how can I set to the second parameter?

Comment: Use your command in your code behind then, i.e. `private void treeView_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
     vm.GetNewTreeViewItemCommand.Execute(new object[] {sender,e});

}`

Comment: BTW passing UI Element (`TreeViewItem`) to your `VM` is bad practise.

Comment: @XAMlMAX if you can show how I can handle without sending `TreeViewItem`, I can upvote your answer. Feel free to answer.

Comment: Simple, move the method from your `ViewModel` to code behind. If you are adding items to your VM collection create command for that, if you are retrieving additional info for this person then create a method in VM to return that info apart from that there is not much more to do.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Neverhteless, `TreeViewItem` will be used in viewmodel:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use another TriggerAction to invoke command in your VM, that will pass args as well:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Person}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <helper:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="TreeViewItem.Expanded">
        <local:CustomCommandAction Command="{Binding GetNewTreeViewItemCommand}"/>
     </helper:RoutedEventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**CustomCommandAction**

```
public sealed class CustomCommandAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            ICommand command = this.Command;
            if (command != null)
            {
                if (this.CommandParameter != null)
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(parameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(parameter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

XAML

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Person}" Grid.Row="1" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <local:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="TreeViewItem.Expanded">
                <local:CustomCommandAction Command="{Binding GetNewTreeViewItemCommand}"/>
            </local:RoutedEventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>
```

VM

```
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Person
    {
        get { return _people; }
    }


    private DelegateCommand _getNewTreeViewItemCommand = null;

    public ICommand GetNewTreeViewItemCommand { get { return _getNewTreeViewItemCommand; } }


    private void LoadNewTreeViewITem(object param)
    {
        var tuple = (Tuple<object, object>)param;

        object sender = tuple.Item1;
        RoutedEventArgs e = tuple.Item2 as RoutedEventArgs;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sender);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.RoutedEvent);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _getNewTreeViewItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoadNewTreeViewITem, (o) => true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var newPerson = new Person() { Description = i.ToString() };
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                newCode.Children.Add(new Person() { Description = i.ToString() + j.ToString() });
            }

            _people.Add(newCode);
        }
    }
```

Person

```
public class Person
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
}
```

Command

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

RoutedEventTrigger

```
public class RoutedEventTrigger : EventTriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    RoutedEvent _routedEvent;

    public RoutedEvent RoutedEvent
    {
        get { return _routedEvent; }
        set { _routedEvent = value; }
    }

    public RoutedEventTrigger()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        Behavior behavior = base.AssociatedObject as Behavior;
        FrameworkElement associatedElement = base.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;

        if (behavior != null)
        {
            associatedElement = ((IAttachedObject)behavior).AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        }
        if (associatedElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Routed Event trigger can only be associated to framework elements");
        }
        if (RoutedEvent != null)
        {
            associatedElement.AddHandler(RoutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnRoutedEvent));
        }
    }
    void OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnEvent(args);
    }
    protected override string GetEventName()
    {
        return RoutedEvent.Name;
    }
}
```

CustomCommandAction

```
public sealed class CustomCommandAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            ICommand command = this.Command;
            if (command != null)
            {
                if (this.CommandParameter != null)
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(parameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(new Tuple<object, object>(this.AssociatedObject, parameter));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use this CustomCommandAction instead of prism:InvokeCommandAction, and it should do the job. If you need to have 2 parameters both, you may change command execution line to something like his: command.Execute(new Tuple<object, object>(this.AssociatedObject, parameter));

Comment: And in your LoadNewTreeViewITem method just extract objects you need from this tuple: LoadNewTreeViewITem(object param) { var tuple = (Tuple<object, object>)param; RoutedEventArgs e = tuple[1] as RoutedEventArgs; ...}

Comment: I've tried your approach, but it gives the first argument, not the second. Now I gonna try to use `Tuple<object, object>`

Comment: please, write the complete example. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I'll write full example, np)

Comment: Updated the answer, so that both sender and args are available in LoadNewTreeViewITem

Comment: Thanks! ooops. I've copied all your code, but I've got an error `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action''`

Comment: Maybe that is because I've used my own DelegateCommand implementation for this example. On what line do you get this error?

Comment: Could you please change your DelegateCommand<RoutedEventArgs> GetNewTreeViewItemCommand { get; set; } to DelegateCommand<object> GetNewTreeViewItemCommand { get; set; }

Comment: man, you are awesome!:) It works like a charm! Thank you very much!:)